# MySQL , JOIN , When total = 1

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i need little help in writing the MYSQL Query.

i want to retreive the data from 3 tables, but i want to retreive the data from 3rd table only if the count() value is equals to 1.

please see the below query.

```
SELECT count(orderdetails.orderId) as total,gadgets.*,orders.* FROM orders
JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderId = orderdetails.orderId
CASE total WHEN 1 THEN (JOIN gadgets ON gadgets.gadgetId = orders.gadgetId)

GROUP BY orders.orderId
ORDER BY orders.orderId DESC;
```

mysql always gives me an error, and i couldnt find any solution over internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a Simple Condition in Join, and it would work (Of course you have make it `Left Join`).

```
SELECT count(orderdetails.orderId) as total,gadgets.*,orders.* FROM orders
JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderId = orderdetails.orderId
LEFT JOIN gadgets ON gadgets.gadgetId = orders.gadgetId
and total=1   --Simple Logic
GROUP BY orders.orderId
ORDER BY orders.orderId DESC;
```

Comment: It would be good if it was valid SQL. You can't reference aliases from `SELECT` list, in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I would have done the same as you have done in your Answer. But i just wanted to give the Logic. Anyways your answer provided the complete answer. +1

Comment: @Luv : i was doing the search and found the people using CASE WHEN , so i just got carried away with it and ending up nowhere. i should have used the LEFT JOIN , thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    g.*, o.* 
FROM 
    orders AS o
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT orderId
      FROM orderdetails 
      GROUP BY orderId
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) AS od 
     ON o.orderId = od.orderId
  JOIN gadgets AS g
    ON g.gadgetId = o.gadgetId
ORDER BY 
    o.orderId DESC ;
```

Comment: Luv answer was working something that i was looking forward for, however your answer have given me a reference and modified the Luv query to completely fit my requirements, thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table and get only results having `total = 1`

```
SELECT count(orderdetails.orderId) as total,gadgets.*,orders.* FROM orders
JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderId = orderdetails.orderId
JOIN gadgets ON gadgets.gadgetId = orders.gadgetId
GROUP BY orders.orderId
HAVING total = 1
ORDER BY orders.orderId DESC;
```

HTH